# Java - System.out.println() viewable from application?

Tags: java, terminal

I have a Java application that runs great :) While uploading files, it uses the standard output to show progress : "System.out.println(...);".

When I run it in Eclipse, well it works perfectly, but when I run the JAR file, I don't see any console/terminal showing up and printing what I print through "System.out.println(...),".

How can I open a new terminal when my application is launched (it is a Swing application)?
Basically I want to be able to run the Swing application and show information on the side in a terminal / console. Why? Don't worry about why I want to do this ;)

Thanks a lot!

Regards.

Comment: Use a logging framework and direct them to a log file. Use log4j/slf4j etc..

Comment: "_Don't worry about why I want to do this_."  - Don't worry, nobody is wondering.  This is one of the most common tasks associated with programming.  Everybody wants to do this!  It's called logging.  Here's [a link to log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/), which is one of the most popular logging frameworks.

Comment: I have tried using the default Logger object that Java has, but even though I'm writing to it, I can't see any console appearing when the application runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open terminal and run application as `java -cp yourjar.jar YouMain` or `java -jar yourjar.jar` if you jar is runnable.

I believe that you do not see output because you are running your application using `javaw` - the special windows-only variation of JVM that does not have STDOUT at all. If you want to click your application and see output map `*.jar` file to be opened using `java` instead of `javaw`. Alternatively write `bat` file that runs your application. In this case you will see console.

Answer (score 1):

Use `java` instead of `javaw` to launch your application. Double-clicking on a jar executes it with `javaw`. Instead, open a command line window and type

```
java -jar thePathOfTheJarFile.jar
```

If you want to have something double-clickable, then write a shell script containing this command, and double-click the shell script instead of the jar.